# Webservice to get City Names by giving Zip Codes

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need a reliable webserivce which gives corresponding city name by passing zip code. This webservice should work at any time. This webservice will be used in the production also.

Comment: either USA or entrire world. First preference is for USA

Answer (score 12):

I found a couple of ways to do this with web based APIs. I think the [US Postal Service](http://www.usps.com/) would be the most accurate, since Zip codes are their thing, but [Ziptastic](http://daspecster.github.com/ziptastic/) looks much easier.

### Using the US Postal Service HTTP/XML API

According to this [page on the US Postal Service website which documents their XML based web API](https://www.usps.com/business/webtools-technical-guides.htm), specifically Section 4.0 (page 22) of [this PDF document](https://www.usps.com/webtools/_pdf/Address-Information-v3-1b.pdf), they have a URL where you can send an XML request containing a 5 digit Zip Code and they will respond with an XML document containing the corresponding City and State.

According to their documentation, here's what you would send:

```
http://SERVERNAME/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=CityStateLookup&XML=<CityStateLookupRequest%20USERID="xxxxxxx"><ZipCode ID= "0"><Zip5>90210</Zip5></ZipCode></CityStateLookupRequest>
```

And here's what you would receive back:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<CityStateLookupResponse> 
    <ZipCode ID="0"> 
        <Zip5>90210</Zip5> 
        <City>BEVERLY HILLS</City> 
        <State>CA</State> 
    </ZipCode> 
</CityStateLookupResponse>
```

USPS *does* require that you register with them before you can use the API, but, as far as I could tell, there is no charge for access. By the way, their API has some other features: you can do Address Standardization and Zip Code Lookup, as well as the whole suite of tracking, shipping, labels, etc.

### Using the Ziptastic HTTP/JSON API

This is a pretty new service, but according to their documentation, it looks like all you need to do is send a GET request to http://ziptasticapi.com, like so:

```
GET http://ziptasticapi.com/48867
```

And they will return a JSON object along the lines of:

```
{"country": "US", "state": "MI", "city": "OWOSSO"}
```

Indeed, it works. You can test this from a command line by doing something like:

```
curl http://ziptasticapi.com/48867
```

Answer (score 5):

http://www.geonames.org/

http://www.geonames.org/postal-codes/

has it for multiple countries

Comment: This looks like a really good bet, you just pass in the ZIP code and then it returns the city name, along with latitude and longitude in a JSON string.

Comment: Getting error while adding this URL as a web reference

Comment: http://www.geonames.org/export/client-libraries.html

Answer (score 2):

perhaps http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?op=GetInfoByZIP
would work for you

Comment: After adding this url as a webreference I am unable to get the methods of the webservice.

Comment: http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx will give you the methods.

Comment: Quick note -- that service doesn't currently support CORS (if anyone else is trying to find an ajax solution).

Comment: This service doesnt give for specific zipcodes. Some examples are :89179,
75965,
72019,
33449,
76549,
75803,
97703,
76210,
84005

Comment: @Sana I think this was a sample service designed for testing web service calls and processing.  I don't believe it was meant to be an actual zip code support service, and there are better ones now...

Comment: @StuartSiegler Can you specify some ?

Comment: @Sana, zipwise is free: https://www.zipwise.com/webservices/

Answer (score 2):

The Yahoo PlaceFinder API will work for this type of query.

http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/guide/index.html

I believe that

```
http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?appid=<appID>&postal=<zipCode>
```

will get you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Also http://www.zipwise.com/webservices gives XML and JSON results for free for zip code lookups, radius searches, reverse lookups, and latitude/longitude stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This may suite your need if you want something to obtain city/state information:

http://www.usps.com/webtools/address.htm

Its a API in which you sign up for.