# Magento get region from zipcode?

Tags: magento

Is it possible to load a region object from just a country code and postcode or a country code and city?

Comment: from where would you get the region object, by sending code or city to some api ?

Comment: I just figured there was something in the core to handle it. So is there no native way to get the state (as in US state) without explicitly adding a dropdown for it or talking to a 3rd part library to do the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

You could do like in this post:

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/geocoding-customer-addresses-in-magento-via-google-maps/

Answer (score 0):

Here was discussed web-serivces which give corresponding city name, region name, region id by passing zip code:

[Webservice to get City Names by giving Zip Codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227527/webservice-to-get-city-names-by-giving-zip-codes)