# Need to get country ,state information based on city name

Tags: web-services

I have list of more than 10,000 cities , I need to find out corresponding state and country of this city. If any built in service  or any web services is   available for this  ,please let me know .

Your help will be appreciated.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227527/webservice-to-get-city-names-by-giving-zip-codes

Comment: FWIW: There are many duplicate city names.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this free database can help you:
http://www.maxmind.com/en/worldcities

Includes the following fields:

```
- Country Code
- ASCII City Name
- City Name
- Region
- Population
- Latitude
- Longitude
```

If you need the states, you can use the database from here: http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/  (the file cities1000.zip has a LOT of cities)